# I want to achieve the styling as done on this website to the header and nav

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to get the styling of the navigation bar of [this site](http://demo.wowsketch.com/spark/). Can anyone explain how to do this?

I want to be able to reduce the size of the navigation `on scroll` and put the image behind the header as [in the website](http://demo.wowsketch.com/spark/).

Can anyone help me on this issue?
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming, you mean the nav bar getting slightly smaller, once you start to scroll and then sticks to the top, with the anchors being highlighted.

Comment: That's right and also the way that image is being placed.

Comment: Which image? the 'Spark' one or the 'John Bravesson'?

Comment: The John Bravessan Image

Comment: just get a transparent logo and stick it 20% from the left and 20px from the top?

Comment: I got the feature done.